# WatchOS2 Watch Connectivity still require app groups in capabilities?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

In the old WatchOS1, app groups was required for any sharing of data.

In WatchOS2, Watch Connectivity replaces the old framework for communication.

I was wondering if app groups is still needed?

Comment: re WatchOS1, "Old" now appears to be  > 2 months. I must be neolithic

Comment: @DavidDelMonte, haha the iPhone 6 is so much different than the iPhone 1, which was 8 years ago... Watch is changing rapidly too! but hey man, we came a long way till today :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, app groups will not help with sharing data between your iOS app and the WatchKit extension. You might however need to use an app group between the WatchKit app and the WatchKit extension as some of the media playing APIs seem to run in the app process.

Comment: "app groups will not help with sharing data between your iOS app and the WatchKit extension. "  the whole point of an app group is creating a shared directory/NSUserDefaults, correct?

Comment: Between sandboxed processes running on the same device. With watchOS 2 and later the iOS app and WatchKit extension are running on the two separate devices